# Best way to deal with 'Can't call setState on an unmounted component' react warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

You guys have probably seen this error, if not it usually looks something like this:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
```

Firstly this isn't a question about what the error means. It seems to me that there are some cases when this warning is (as far as I can tell) a bit unjustified.

Consider this component

```
() => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <p>Is foo: {foo}</p>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setFoo(true)
        window.setTimeout(() => setFoo(false), 1000)
      }}>Click me</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Ok, so in this contrived example we wanna show `Is foo: true` for 1 second after the button is clicked. If the component unmounts during that second it's going to call setFoo and we'll get that warning. As far as I can tell, this isn't a memory leak. It might be holding onto setFoo a bit longer than necessary but this won't build up over time, the timer will release setFoo albeit slightly later than it could. Am I missing something? My boss is telling me to get rid of the warning but to cancel the timeout adds a bunch of complexity to something which shouldn't be complex, and imo not going to offer any meaningful performance benefit.

This lead me to this idea:

```
export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => () => setState(false), [])
  return state
}
```

```
const useSafeState = <T extends unknown>(defaultState: T): [T, (newState: T) => void] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(defaultState)
  const isMounted = useIsMounted()

  return [
    state,
    (newState: T) => {
      if (isMounted) {
        setState(newState)
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

by changing the first example to use `useSafeState` it automatically checks, effectively suppressing the warning. What do you guys think of this? Use safe state functionally does nothing, because as the react warning states it's a no op. I feel like the warning is there for when people forget to cancel their setIntervals from their useEffect, but for these other scenarios we're forced to do something silly like this just to get rid of the warning.

Thoughts?

Comment: you need to clear the setTimeout in the useEffects return

Comment: @DerekPollard hey, thanks for the response. My question is more about why/if we actually need to clear it in some situations. Especially ones where the timeout is being created in response to an event like onClick as opposed to in an effect. If you think it's necessary create a separate useEffect and keep track of the event handle (which is kind of messy) could you explain why?

Comment: Yes, you need to do it, this is an indicator of a memory leak

Comment: Its always good to be responsible and clean up resources which are no longer used. In this case you would keep a reference to `setFoo` around, preventing it from being vacuumed. Here you are using a timeout so, the timeout would eventually run. But it could also cause trouble down the road if someone decided to lift the foo state out of this component and you would affect the state after leaving this component as the timer wasn't being stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear out the timer in useEffect's return value:

#### Working example

```
function TimeoutExample() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false)
  const counterRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (counterRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(counterRef.current);
        counterRef.current = null
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (counterRef.current) return;
    setFoo(true);
    counterRef.current = setTimeout(() => setFoo(false), 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Is foo: {foo}</p>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: If you are a bad user and click the button multiple times here it would lose track of existing timeouts as it only keeps track of the last one. So if you were to click 10 times (within the 1000 ms) and then unmount the component only the last timer would be cleared, and 9 warnings should follow :)

Answer (score 0):

[React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) offers some examples on how and why one might need to do cleanup.

> Earlier, we looked at how to express side effects that don’t require
> any cleanup. However, some effects do. For example, we might want to
> set up a subscription to some external data source. In that case, it
> is important to clean up so that we don’t introduce a memory leak!
> Let’s compare how we can do it with classes and with Hooks.

While the `setTimeout` example may be contrived, it would be better to handle cleanup as required over using something like the `useSafeState` as that would not necessarily avoid potential memory leaks, even if it in this case block the call to `setState`. Might save you from a crash or leave less things running for your user improving their experience on your site!

Using the return value of `useEffect` you can clear the current timer when the component ends up being unmounted by returning a function to do cleanup.

Your component could look something like this:

```js
() => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(false)
  const timeout = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
      }
  }, [])

  const handleClick = () => {
    setFoo(true);
    
    if (timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
    
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => setFoo(false), 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Is foo: {foo}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Having a click based useEffect is considered bad practice; it isn't directly obvious what is initiating the timer which causes DeX issues

Comment: @Justice DeX issues? DX? developer experience? Or something else? I agree its not directly obvious in one sense. Even if you have the dependency array hinting at the source. Please elaborate on the bad practice tho!

Comment: Yes, developer experience - side effects like these should be kept in a useCallback or arrow function (depending on how particular about rerender management).

Comment: Otherwise, you end up in a situation where you're reliant on an external side effect tangentially related to the click handler.

Comment: For sample, if we needed to mutate this value, but didn't want to set the timeout

Comment: @justice for this case, this example code is perfectly fine. It gets the point across

Comment: @Justice true, especially if you want to change it outside of this without the same effect. But the example was kind of small scale. But agreed on co-locating side effects. For that it would make more sense to create a handler function like in the other answer. For example here if it should always show for 1 second since the last interaction it wont either.

Comment: Yeah so Derek answer is better